# How to save a json object in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-urls

i am trying to develop a system which displays a list of experts in a topic when that particular topic is searched. The search function is working and the list of experts (result) is generated from an API which is in form of a list of json objects as shown below:

```
result={
        "experts":[
  {
    "thumbnail": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=small_photo&user=JicYPdAAAAAJ&citpid=2",
    "name": "Geoffrey Hinton",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=JicYPdAAAAAJ",
    "author_id": "JicYPdAAAAAJ",
    "email": "Verified email at cs.toronto.edu",
    "affiliations": "Emeritus Prof. Comp Sci, U.Toronto & Engineering Fellow, Google",
    "cited_by": 638900,
    "interests": [
      {
        "title": "machine learning",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Amachine_learning",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:machine_learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "psychology",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Apsychology",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:psychology"
      },
      {
        "title": "artificial intelligence",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aartificial_intelligence",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:artificial_intelligence"
      },
      {
        "title": "cognitive science",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Acognitive_science",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:cognitive_science"
      },
      {
        "title": "computer science",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Acomputer_science",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:computer_science"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "thumbnail": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=small_photo&user=kukA0LcAAAAJ&citpid=3",
    "name": "Yoshua Bengio",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=kukA0LcAAAAJ",
    "author_id": "kukA0LcAAAAJ",
    "email": "Verified email at umontreal.ca",
    "affiliations": "Professor of computer science, University of Montreal, Mila, IVADO, CIFAR",
    "cited_by": 605714,
    "interests": [
      {
        "title": "Machine learning",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Amachine_learning",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:machine_learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "deep learning",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Adeep_learning",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:deep_learning"
      },
      {
        "title": "artificial intelligence",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aartificial_intelligence",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:artificial_intelligence"
      }
    ]
  }
        ]
    }
```

Now this "result" object is directly passed to an appropriate html template.Each "expert" in the "experts" list is iterated and displayed in the html page as shown:
[image: results page]

I want the user to be able to save the data of each individual expert.So I added a "Save" button beside each expert result.At the moment I cannot figure out out how to  get all the data of an "expert" json object when the user clicks on the "Save" button beside each result.How do I create a URL pattern that can get the entire "expert" json object when the user clicks on the "Save" button and this json object can then be stored in database?

Comment: why not create a url path like `/expert/{author_id}` that gives the id of an expert to be able to download the specific expert's info.

Comment: Save where? any defined model?

Comment: @HemaPatel Not decided on the model yet.But somehow I want to save all the data about the expert.What kind of model should I define to save a json object?

Comment: @AndrewRyan I am using paid API.So I dont want to call the same API multiple times.I just want to save the already existing json data of an expert when the user clicks on the save button

Comment: how are you looking to save the object (to the database of the django framework or to a file on the website user's computer?) What does the HTML Template look like (the template is formatting the data correct?)

Comment: @AndrewRyan I am looking to save the data to the database.I am just getting the json data from the API and passing this to the html template as the context object named "experts".Then in the html template I iterate through that context object named "experts" and display each expert data as shown below
<tbody>
                                                  {% for expert in experts%} 
           
                                                        </td>{{expert.name}} </td>
                                                  
                                                  {%endfor}

Comment: @AndrewRyan I just render and show some of the details in the html page but the full json data of the expert is passed to the html template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a view that receive the expert id and the info you want to pass, and in it you can save the info to the db.

Steps:

- The href attr of the 'Save' will be as the following:
  `{% url 'your_view_name' expert.id %}`
- Override the `post` method of your view.
- In the `post` method you will get expert.id parameter, get the expert info then update the db.

The tricky part in those steps is how to get the expert data from its id?
You can request the api another time and get this expert info then save them as you want, OR to reduce the calls of the api and make them one call for each cycle you can use caching for the response by redis for example or you can store the responses of the api in your db.

Comment: I thinks that's a good idea.

Comment: Could you explain more on the "tricky" part.Is it like I pass the self.experts to my html template?

Comment: I edited the answer (The tricky part of the answer).